# PHP: empty folders when uploading an image to multiple folders

Tags: php, image-uploading

I've got a very strange behaviour when I'm uploading an image to multiple folders. I'm trying to add the uploaded images to 3 different folders:

- /userimg/original (just the original picture)
- /userimg/100x100 (100px width and 100px heigh + do crop)
- /userimg/1000x1000 (max 1000px width and max 1000px height)

My script fills the first folder with all selected images (in $_FILES), but the other folders are not filled at all. If I put the '100x100'-folder first in my dimensions array, then that's the folder that is filled with images while the others aren't. I've been debugging for 2 days now and I'm getting a little bit nervous :P

Here's my script:

```
<?php

App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');

class UserImage extends CoasterCmsAppModel
{
    public $useTable = false;

    /** @var array $dimensions Dimensions for photo resizing. */
    public $dimensions = array(
        array(
            'width' => 999999,
            'height' => 999999,
            'crop' => false,
            'autocrop' => false,
            'quality' => 100,
            'folder' => 'original'
        ),
        array(
            'width' => 100,
            'height' => 100,
            'crop' => true,
            'autocrop' => true,
            'quality' => 60,
            'folder' => '100x100'
        ),
        array(
            'width' => 1000,
            'height' => 1000,
            'crop' => false,
            'autocrop' => true,
            'quality' => 80,
            'folder' => '1000x1000'
        )
    );

    public function uploadImages($images) {// this function is called to process the images. $images = $_FILES
        if (!$images || !is_array($images)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(
                __('Invalid data.')
            );
        }

        App::import('Component', 'ImageCropResize.Image');
        $image = new ImageComponent(new ComponentCollection);

        $userImgFolder = WWW_ROOT . 'userimg' . DS;

        foreach ($this->dimensions as $dimension) {
            $userImgDimensionFolder = $userImgFolder . $dimension['folder'] . DS;
            $folder = new Folder($userImgDimensionFolder);

            if (is_null($folder->path)) {
                $folder->create($userImgDimensionFolder, 0755);
            }
        }

        $jsonArray = [];

        foreach ($images['name'] as $key => $imageName) {
            $imageNameCleaned = basename($imageName);
            $imageNameCleaned = str_replace(' ', '-', $imageNameCleaned);
            $imageNameCleaned = strtolower($imageNameCleaned);
            $imageNameCleaned = time() . '-' . $imageNameCleaned;

            foreach ($this->dimensions as $dimension) {
                $userImgDimensionFolder = $userImgFolder . $dimension['folder'] . DS;

                $imagePath = $userImgDimensionFolder . $imageNameCleaned;

                move_uploaded_file($images['tmp_name'][$key], $imagePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Extra info:** here's an example of my $images-array that is loaded into the 'uploadImages' function:

```
array(
    'name' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1.jpg',
        (int) 1 => '2.jpg',
        (int) 2 => '3.jpg',
        (int) 3 => '4.jpg',
        (int) 4 => '5.jpg',
        (int) 5 => '6.jpg',
        (int) 6 => '7.JPG',
        (int) 7 => '8.jpg'
    ),
    'type' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'image/jpeg',
        (int) 1 => 'image/jpeg',
        (int) 2 => 'image/jpeg',
        (int) 3 => 'image/jpeg',
        (int) 4 => 'image/jpeg',
        (int) 5 => 'image/jpeg',
        (int) 6 => 'image/jpeg',
        (int) 7 => 'image/jpeg'
    ),
    'tmp_name' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB877.tmp',
        (int) 1 => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB897.tmp',
        (int) 2 => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB898.tmp',
        (int) 3 => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB8A9.tmp',
        (int) 4 => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB8AA.tmp',
        (int) 5 => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB8AB.tmp',
        (int) 6 => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB8AC.tmp',
        (int) 7 => 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB8AD.tmp'
    ),
    'error' => array(
        (int) 0 => (int) 0,
        (int) 1 => (int) 0,
        (int) 2 => (int) 0,
        (int) 3 => (int) 0,
        (int) 4 => (int) 0,
        (int) 5 => (int) 0,
        (int) 6 => (int) 0,
        (int) 7 => (int) 0
    ),
    'size' => array(
        (int) 0 => (int) 4498964,
        (int) 1 => (int) 372372,
        (int) 2 => (int) 219612,
        (int) 3 => (int) 15807,
        (int) 4 => (int) 91903,
        (int) 5 => (int) 56157,
        (int) 6 => (int) 138041,
        (int) 7 => (int) 81819
    )
)
```

Any thoughts to guide me into the right direction?
And yes, I do appreciate some extra tips and hints about my PHP code ;)

**Edit 1 after feedback by Dorvalla**

Here's my new $dimensions array, but this seems not to work:

```
public $dimensions = array(
    0 => array(
        'width' => 999999,
        'height' => 999999,
        'crop' => false,
        'autocrop' => false,
        'quality' => 100,
        'folder' => 'original'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'width' => 100,
        'height' => 100,
        'crop' => true,
        'autocrop' => true,
        'quality' => 60,
        'folder' => '100x100'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'width' => 1000,
        'height' => 1000,
        'crop' => false,
        'autocrop' => true,
        'quality' => 80,
        'folder' => '1000x1000'
    )
);
```

Comment: your array has no unique key, thus it overwrites the array always. This is because you always output the same fields within the array, can you print out the array as you see it in code when doing this action

Comment: I've changed my $dimensions array as you asked. See 'edit 1' in my original post. But there's not realy an improvement. The other folders (100x100 and 1000x1000) are still empty.

Comment: does all folders exists in the file system and the owner has permissions to write and execute on it?

Comment: Yes, they do exist and they are all writable. I've tested this by adding the folders manually and by changing the persmissions inside my script. See $folder->create($userImgDimensionFolder, 0755);

Comment: The directory would already have to exist.

Comment: Changing the permission on the php script itself won't mean anything at all if PHP does not have permission to rewrite permissions. Also, are you on a shared hosting?

Comment: move_uploaded_file **moves** the file to a new location (clue's in the name!!). So once it's been moved, it's (obviously) no longer in its original location. In your code you've written `move_uploaded_file($images['tmp_name'][$key], $imagePath);` inside a loop, so it will be executed multiple times. However, after the first time you ran it, the file no longer exists at the location pointed to by `$images['tmp_name'][$key]`, so you can't move it from there again. You can only move it once. After that, to make additional copies you need to copy it from the place you moved it to.

Comment: Gokigooooks, thanks for the clarification and yes: the website runs on a shared hosting (Easyhost).
@ADyson: seems very obvious indeed. But with that said, I don't understand why there are 8 moved images in the '/original/'-folder instead of only 1. Is there a sort of 'hook' after the first image was uploaded into the '/original/'-folder so you don't need to change directory anymore? Dunno if this is a stupid thought :)